# How can I change type of input func arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
num = input('Select faces of Dice between [4, 6, 8, 12, 20].\n')
my_dice=Dice(int(num))
com_dice=Dice(int(num))
```

In class `Dice`, the `__init__` method compares `num` with `[4,6,8,12,20]`, and if there isn't a match, it prints an error message. I tried but it always print error message even if I enter `4` or `6`. I thought `input` get its argument with type `str`, so I changed `Dice(num)` into `Dice(int(num))` then it worked.

I want to know how I can get its argument type `int` when I enter it.

I'm using repl.it, with Python 3.

Comment: So it printed an error message - but you somehow didn't think that the *exact text* of that message was relevant?  It would, at the very least, tell you *where* the error occurred - which I suspect is in `Dice()`, rather than the code you posted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` function always returns a string. This is a lot better than sometimes returning different types, depending on the text entered by the user! Python 2's `input` worked that way and it was a mess.

If you want `num` to be an integer, you can convert the string returned by `input` into an `int` directly:

```
num = int(input('Select faces of Dice between [4, 6, 8, 12, 20].\n'))
```

This is a little fragile though, as it will raise an exception if the user enters a non-integer value. If you want to print a nicer error message, you'll either need to write exception handling code, or you will want to save the string first, and check if it's numeric before attempting to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

According to python documentation here 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

```
input([prompt])
```

If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised. Example:

```
>>>
>>> s = input('--> ')  
--> Monty Python's Flying Circus
>>> s  
"Monty Python's Flying Circus"
```

It will convert it to string by default so you may continue to convert it after accepting the input.
I hope this will be helpful to understand.